# Exposing GRPC service via AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, grpc, terraform-provider-aws

I have a GRPC server running in my docker container and I am trying to expose the grpc printer connection server to the outside world via a subdomain in my server.

I created a ALB target :

```
resource "aws_alb_target_group" "main_printer" {
  name_prefix      = "print"
  port             = var.container_printer_port
  protocol         = "HTTPS"
  protocol_version = "GRPC"
  vpc_id           = var.vpc_id
  target_type      = "ip"

  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.name}-tg-printer-${var.environment}"
    Environment = var.environment
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

data "aws_acm_certificate" "certificate_printer" {
  domain      = var.website_printer_fqdn
  statuses    = ["ISSUED"]
  most_recent = true

  depends_on = [
    var.cert_printer_validation_id,
  ]
}

resource "aws_alb_listener_rule" "main_printer" {
  listener_arn = aws_alb_listener.https.arn
  priority     = 40

  condition {
    host_header {
      values = [var.website_printer_fqdn]
    }
  }

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.main_printer.arn
  }
}

resource "aws_alb_listener_certificate" "main_printer" {
  listener_arn    = aws_alb_listener.https.arn
  certificate_arn = data.aws_acm_certificate.certificate_printer.arn
}
```

I added the following ingres to the security group

```
ingress {
    protocol  = "tcp"
    from_port = var.container_printer_port
    to_port   = var.container_printer_port
    security_groups = [
      aws_security_group.alb.id,
      aws_security_group.bastion.id,
    ]
  }
```

But when I try to connect to the server, I get error `Caused by: java.io.IOException: FRAME_SIZE_ERROR: 4740180` which seems to indicate that I am getting a HTTP 1.1 frame instead of the GRPC frame that is required.

Any help in trying to debug this issue is appreciated.